# FILE (.json) NOT FOUND

Tags: python, json, python-requests, ocr, google-vision

This is my directory where i have activated a virtual environment:

[image: The directory where I have activated a virtual environment]

I'm working on a flask project to create a rest API, and I have a JSON credential file (google vision file), but when I run the code it says file not found even if it's in the same directory. I've activated a virtualenv for this particular project. `mainone.py` is the code I'm trying to run.

This is the error I am getting:

```
"File {} was not found.".format(filename)
google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: File date_scanner.json was not found.
```

And this is the code block where I am using accessing the particular file:

```
from flask import Flask,request,jsonify
import os,io,re,glob,base64
from google.cloud import vision
from google.cloud.vision import types
from PIL import Image

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS']=r'date_scanner.json'
client=vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
```

Comment: Try using the full path, something like "D:\\python\\path\\to\\file.json"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely because the "working folder" of the Python process is not the same as where the file is located. There is a small (albeit convoluted) way to generate filenames which will always work:

1. Use `__file__` to get the filename of the Python file where this is called.
2. Strip the filename from that path using `os.path.dirname`
3. Append the filename that you want to open using `os.path.join`

```
from os.path import dirname, join


def get_filename(filename):
    here = dirname(__file__)
    output = join(here, filename)
    return output
```

#### Some food for thought

However, in this case there is something you should be careful about: The file contains security credentials and should *not* live in your source code. So while the above example will solve the immediate problem, the security of this should be addressed.

The best way for this is to externalise the filename of the credentials file into a config file. Say, for example you would use a `.ini` file as config file, you could have something like this in your code somewhere:

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')
vision_creds_file = config.get('google_vision', 'filename')
```

and then place the following into `config.ini`:

```
[google_vision]
filename = /path/to/filename.json
```

This still requires you to place the `config.ini` file somewhere which should be documented in your application, as you still cannot add this to the source code (maybe a sample file with defaults).

Comment: thank you for replying :),but there is an image link ive posted in the question please check that once .

Comment: I did check the image link. The above code is still correct. I also added some details about security concerns into the answer.

Comment: I'm really grateful for this , I'm new to making projects using google ocr and using different libraries so i havn't quite understood what you meant in the 2nd part about the security concerns .But i will followup on it . Thanks a lot

Comment: It can be summarised like this: You should never consider access credentials as part of your code. They should not be distributed with your code. When installing your application, the credentials file should be created in a separate Imagine installing the same app twice for different users with different credentials. This should always be possible. If the credentials file is part of your code this will not work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking your time and explaining , Really grateful .